Downloading and replacing app container doesn’t work
I used to download and replace the app container when I was testing, essentially downloading the container from the live app, and restoring it into the test app in order to not affect the live app, but to test major changes on "live" data.
it seems the option for downloading and replacing in Xcode no longer works, I will sometimes get a container downloaded, other times it only part downloads. I can never seem to get it to replace. No errors, but it doesn't work on the new device.
It used to be that devices & simulators showed when it was downloading and replacing but it no longer does that.
Is there another way of doing this? Currently I'm having to take a backup of the live phone, restore on the test device, then delete all the unneeded apps, otherwise the restore takes ages, then backup the test device and restore every time I need to restart.
